# Remove ONE (without id) element from UL jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags, append, cloud

Hi!

My problem is that I'm appending to an UL like that:

```
$("#tagek").append("<li><a>"+arr[0]+"</a><span class='ex'><a>X</a></span></li>");
```

So just shortly: I want to make a tag cloud. When someone types a comma, add the tag to the ul list. That works like charm, however I want to add an "X" to the li element so when someone clicks on it, it will be removed.
Something like that:

```
$(document).on('click','.ex',function(){
var li = $('.ex').closest("li");
li.remove();
});
```

So when I click on the ".ex" span its' li should disappear. This is working, but EVERY li is removed (logically), because every "X" has the same class.

Any ideas on this?

Maybe with .eq()?

Thank you.

Comment: create jsfiddle please

Comment: you have bad layout, tag a inside span is bad because this tag have two required attributes alt and href, li for ex is parent...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are experimenting that behaviour because you're removing the closest 'li' of every '.ex' element instead of the one clicked. Use the $(this) selector in the handler instead:

Try:

```
$(document).on('click','.ex',function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're re-selecting `.ex` (which gets all of them) inside the function handler instead of using the one that the event was triggered by.

Fix:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ex', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

Edit: Not enough karma to comment, but alex030293's code should execute faster, but assumes that the element is a direct child as opposed to a descendant. If this is always the case, it's better to use his code. If there might be a situation where the `.ex` element is encapsulated in another tag, it's better to use mine.

Comment: You redditor... its a reputation here.

Comment: This is also working, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I can only mark one answer correct. :(

Answer (score 1):

i think u need this if you are using jquery .

```
    $(document).on('click','.ex',function(){
    var li = $(this).closest("li");
    li.remove();
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working too. Unfortunately I can only mark one answer correct. :(